# How to show annotation for every point on highchart then disappear them

Tags: javascript, highcharts, annotations

I'm using highchart and I have some annotation on it, but all annotation is load first,
I decreased the series animation duration to 10000, The question is how can I show one by one annotations on the chart?

I mean I want to show first annotation on series then disappear the first and show the second and so on.

show this image that I found on the internet:

[image]

I will appreciate sharing your data with me,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prepared a demo which shows how to keep tooltip shown for the last point.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vL7k1yce/

```
  render() {
    let chart = this,
      points = chart.series[0].points;
    chart.tooltip.refresh(points[points.length - 1]);
  }
```

Is that what you wanted to achieve?

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

Comment: Thanks Sebastian ,how implement this in this demo chart? 
highcharts.com/demo/stock/basic-line

Comment: In the Highstock the tooltip is shared so the argument taken to the refresh function must be in array: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lcfvtwsr/

Comment: What else would you like to have?

Comment: this just shows one tooltip, not show tooltip of every point on chart

Comment: I mean in the highstock that you sent jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lcfvtwsr  not show tooltip on every point, it just shows only last tooltip on chart.

Comment: And I prefer to show annotation instead of tooltip in chart

Comment: Let me clarify - would you like to display only the annotation for the last point in the series? Your gif attached in the question suggests showing the tooltip.

Comment: I want to display annotations on specific points as the series reach that points, I also need to have all previous annotations (no disappearing after display)

Comment: Please Show This: https://jsfiddle.net/Yarandi/ce3hqbg5/2/
This chart has some annotations but all annotations display before point reach them, 
they display in the first load, I want to show them when the point is reached (one by one) and don't disappear them after reached, Hope its clear :)

Comment: Something like is done here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r6ns4we5/ is your requirment?

Comment: Yes Exactly is, But I need to implement on highstock chart.

Comment: So where is the problem with implementing it in the Highstock? May I see your attempt with the sample data which you are using?

Comment: Check it please: https://jsfiddle.net/Yarandi/be09xfdr/4/
I can not get x values for check conditions , it shows only last point , check the console log

Comment: @HamedYarandi Could you explain for which points would you like to display those annotations?

Comment: Please check it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8sj1yLf6/